# Gentiles/Noahides and Yom Kippur

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, gentiles, yom-kippur

Can Gentiles/Noahides participate in Yom Kippur and to what extent? I have read by some Rabbis that they not only can but should! Biblical resources would be most helpful.

Shalom!

Comment: Hi charles and [welcome to Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites/3887#3887)! It's great to have you learn here with us - hope to see you around.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a moment to look at our [tour] where you’ll find some useful information on how the site works. Thank you for bringing this intriguing question to our attention; I’ve helped you out with fixing your typos and putting better tags on your question, but you can always [edit] it to revert my changes or to edit it further. I hope you enjoy the community, and have a sweet new year!

Comment: Thank you! I was directed here by a dear Jewish friend on another forum. Thank HaShem I have found a great community online and hope to continue to grow that community over here.

Comment: Just to clarify what you mean by “participate:” do you mean attending shul? Do you mean hearing the shofar on Rosh Hashanah and fasting on Yom Kippur? Do you mean eating the apple in honey on Rosh Hashanah? Any and all of the above?

Comment: Mostly the apples and honey :) honestly, I am most focused on Yom Kippur and teshuva. Prayers and seeking repentance

Comment: Biblical resources? I don't think you'll find much in the Tanach about this

Comment: The basics are in there but not the prayers or explanations. Talmud or commentary?