# While studying for the purpose of conversion, is it acceptable to observe Yom Kippur?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, yom-kippur, rosh-hashanah-new-year, high-holidays

I have studied Judaism on my own for a little over two years and I do have the FULL intent to ultimately convert. I live in a very rural area in the south, so Jewish communities are few and far between, so I do not yet have a Rabbi to ask in this instance (however, I have coordinated with the closest one to me and will be meeting with him after the High Holidays!) All of this in mind, I've been told that as part of the conversion process, one should "live a Jewish lifestyle." Does this include observing Yom Kippur? It recently occurred to me that observing Jewish holy days may be seen as appropriative or offensive, and that is the last thing I want to do. I welcome your thoughts graciously.

Comment: This is something you have to ask the rabbi closest to you. There are many possible answers but the only right one is the one he gives you

Comment: Offhand overall thinking - There is a prohibition for a Gentile to observe Shabbat in the same ways as Jews do, particularly in terms of not doing *melachot* ("work"). In that sense, Yom Kippur is like Shabbat. However, there is no problem with either repentance or fasting on Yom Kippur as far as I can tell. Other religions have fast days, and repentance is a common and noble action of humanity. Additionally, as has been stated in MY, there is no problem with Gentiles praying in a synagogue. (Check with the cong's rabbi, esp. on YK, as most places have "stricter" policies on these days.)

Comment: It sounds like you're already in contact with a rabbi. That's great. For this kind of question he'll be happy to answer it for you even before you formally meet. Just give him a call

Comment: Taylor, I wanted to officially [welcome you to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501). Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  We have many other [tag:conversion-to-judaism] questions you might find of interest. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Double AA, if a question seems too personal, why not edit it so it is impersonal rather than throwing it out?  I have done so.

Comment: @Mau https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4774/759 https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3873/759

Comment: related: [Gentiles/Noahides and Yom Kippur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95215/11501)